# JpGraph Error: 25001 This PHP installation is not configured with the GD library

Tags: php, windows, apache, gd

I have a PHP application that is running under WAMP and using JPGraph. It all works fine. I am trying to now deploy the application on a production web server which, rather than running WAMP, runs native Apache and PHP, and am receiving the following error:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant IMG_PNG - assumed 'IMG_PNG' in C:\Program Files\Adaptive\webPortal\models\jpgraph\jpgraph_errhandler.inc.php on line 282
JpGraph Error: 25001 This PHP installation is not configured with the GD library. Please recompile PHP with GD support to run JpGraph. (Neither function imagetypes() nor imagecreatefromstring() does exist)
```

Now obviously I have ran up `phpinfo()` and, as expected, there is no GD enabled on the production server. The only difference I can see is in the version of PHP; WAMP is bundled with PHP **5.4.12** and the production server has installed PHP **5.3.29**, so a slightly earlier version. The issue is this has to run on Windows, and I can't find a Windows PHP installation for any version greater than 5.3.29.

However, I see no reason why I can't just enable GD on the production server. BUT:

- The extension=php_gd2.dll line is uncommented in php.ini
- php_gd2.dll exists in \PHP\ext

So... yeah. I'm kind of stuck haha. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check comment from JB here: http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.extensions.php#90681

Comment: I assume this is talking about the environment variable PATH? I have added the ext directory in with no change, do I need to restart the PC?

Comment: I suppose so. Depending on where you configured it, you may at least need to restart Apache, and possibly even the computer indeed.